# Obj-c - Two different tableView cells overlapping eachother?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two different custom tableview cells inside my tableview. That said, one of the cells is set to be sized according to how much text is placed in it (E.g. if the user types 5 lines of text, the cell should size to fit all 5 lines). The other cell should always return at height 212. When I execute this however, sometimes my cells are returned overlapping each other in the tableview?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSDictionary *data = self.messages[indexPath.row];

    id swaptime = data[@"swaptime"];

    if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

        return 212;

    } else {

       return tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;



    }

}
```

Comment: I think you have some problem with constraints in the first cell. Try to show in without the second cell.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov It works completely fine without the addition of the cell w the static height (212). Any idea what sort of constraint could be messing things up?

Comment: It is strange. Do you implement estimatedSize method?  As quick solution, you can add height constraint for the  second cell and return UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: Ahhh yep. Found the constraint error @AndrewRomanov in my static cell. Thanks so much :)